# Searching through array integer column with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in my app I have table users that have the following column:

```
t.integer  "administrations", array: true
```

and I have code that looks like this:

```
User.where("administrations::int[] = ARRAY[#{administration_ids.join(',') }]::int[]")
```

but it is vulnerable for sql injection. I was trying to rewrite those to something like that:

```
User.where("administrations::int[] = ?", "ARRAY[#{administration_ids.join(',') }]::int[]")
```

but this not works...

It returns:

```
PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  array value must start with "{" or dimension information
```

Answer (score 1):

would

```
User.where("administrations::int[] = ARRAY[?]::int[]", administration_ids.join(','))
```

work?

Comment: Unfortunately it not works :(
       PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "9696,9695,9694"

Answer (score 0):

Also something like this work:

```
User.where(administrations: '{15,26,62,89,121}')
```